# Right angle related to angle bisectors

Tags: geometry

everyone.

$AD$,$BE$,$CF$ are the angle bisectors of $\triangle ABC$, where $D$,$E$,$F$ are on $BC$,$CA$,$AB$ respectively.
Let $BE\cap DF=H$ (Sorry, I omitted this)

Show that if $\angle CFD=\angle BED$, $\angle HAE$ is right-angle, with no use of $\angle BAC$.

Comment: The question asks about a point $H$ but does not say where $H$ is.  Is this a typo?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I omitted the condition.

Comment: Geogebra shows that just∠CFD =∠BED alone cannot guarantee ∠HAE is a right-angle, unless there is another given condition like A is the center of the circle passing through F, H, and E.